# How to show HTML5 video on line

Tags: html5-video

I'm a new developer. I've created a simple HTML5 page and this is the first time I'm using HTML5 to display a video.

My problem is: I could view the video on my local machine however I can not see it online.

Can someone help to make this video work online?

here is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm" />
        <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: here is the code : 



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm" />
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Can you access directly your videos online ? You may have forget to authorize to read them or something like that

Comment: when i tested only the video like that : www.my-website.com/movie.mp4   

i had  this error page :

The page cannot be found
The page you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
Please try the following:

....

Comment: and when i tested  my video like that : www.my-website.com/videoo.html

I did not have anything, the video can not be started

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

You will, of course, have to put the correct `src` for the file you want to play. Finding the correct path would depend on the server/hosting you are using but if you know how to upload the video online, you should be able to figure out what the correct path is as well. Posting some code in your question would help give you a better answer.

Comment: my video.mp4 is on the same level as my HTML page. the code is working fine on my local but not on line, i'm sure that the path is correct,  i've posted  my code in my first comment

Comment: Based on your comments below your question - it seems that the path is not correct if you are getting "The page cannot be found" when you try to access the video directly. Can you post the file structure on your server and also check the permissions on that file you are trying to display?

Comment: I assure you that the path is correct, I usually upload files to the server.
Moreover, my HTML page and the video are on the same root.

I tested with a picture like that : www.my-website.com/picture.jpg  and I could see the image but when I try to access the video directly it does not work.

Would not it be a problem of law at the server


PS : my picture, my video and my html page are on the same path

Comment: If you cannot access the video directly, the HTML is not going to see it either. Hard to debug without having more information but apart from the permissions, check for typos in the name or even caps and lower case letters.